# jquerymobile to change icon in selectmenu

Tags: jquery-mobile, select-menu

Hopefully this is really straightforward and simple. I can't select the selectmenu in JQM.  please see the jsfiddle at the bottom.

I just want to dynamically change the icon from downarrow to star. I can't seem to even 'select' the selectmenu though using an id. Only badly using a class. I've left in a few of the tonnes of things I've tried, can someone show how to do it properly please.

I was expecting this to work. But I've tried this and lots more with no luck.

```
$('#foo').selectmenu({ icon: "star" });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whu3jL7c/5/)

http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#option-iconpos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to call it before the page is created, here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whu3jL7c/8/) with the pagebeforecreate.

  ```
  $(document).on( "pagebeforecreate", "#page", function( event ){
      $('select').selectmenu({ icon: "star", iconpos: "left" });
  });`
  ```
- You could use the removeClass and addClass on the parent of the select instead of the select itself after the page is created : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whu3jL7c/7/)

Do you absolutely need to do it dynamically ?
Otherwise you could just use the data attributes :

```
data-icon="star" data-iconpos="left"
```

Comment: Yes. I know i can just do it like, but this is actually part of a larger bit of coding which I have simplified down. However, I seem to be failing at the first step and not being able to select it.

Comment: You have to call it before the page is created, here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whu3jL7c/8/) with the pagebeforecreate.

Comment: thank you. I saw your comment with `$(".selector").parent().removeClass("ui-btn-icon-right");` also.  Both are very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Cleaned up my answer, the best way to  do it I think is to call it before the page is created :)

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/whu3jL7c/11/) is a jsfiddle of a more completed / neater coding. Using the .parent() aspect seems to work well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the icon after the widget has been initialized, you can call selectmenu("destroy") and then reinitialize:

```
$('#foo').selectmenu("destroy").selectmenu({
    icon: "star",
    iconpos: "left"
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/whu3jL7c/13/)**

In the demo click the button to see the icon change to a star and move to the left.